# Three.js Camera is focusing Only at Origin

Tags: java, three.js, collada

I have drawn a path(line) around the origin, i want to move the camera along with line. But the camera is always facing towards the Origin. But as per my Project specification i have to travel along the continuation of the line.]

[image: Geometry Generated Dynamically using MeshBasicMaterial]

camera is travelling(camera.Position.set(x,y,z) from A to B in a correct way.
but when it is traveling from B to C and C to D etc , camera is facing origin not the Line.My requirement is camera should focus the line not the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have something like this in your code:

```
camera.target = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
...
function render(){
    ...
    camera.lookAt(camera.target);
    ...
}
```

In that case upon reaching point **B** you should make point **C** a new camera target.

```
camera.target = pointC.position.clone();
```